# Unable to start the process of nhttp.exe on my local machine using Notes 9

Tags: port, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have IBM Notes 9.0.1 (Revision 20131022.1138) installed on my Windows 8.1. Whenever I start my Domino Designer and try to preview a page it does not show up. I tried to start the local HTTP process using the command `nhttp.exe -preview` but it gave me an error as:

> HTTP Server: Error - Unable to Bind port 80, port may be in use or
>   user needs net_privaddr privilege

Using the command of `netstat -o` I was able to find `Toaster.exe` process bound to 80. I disabled it using instructions from [here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3513/t/19427665.aspx). But still I am getting the same error. Now the `netstat -o` command does not show any process bound to port 80.

Taking reference from [this discussion](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/0/2b9de53af273fd83852575520030e9ef?OpenDocument) I even disabled my Windows firewall but I am still unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will work - but have you tried changing the Web Preview port in Domino Designer -> Preferences -> Domino Designer -> Web Preview Port. Change it to 8080 or something other than 80 that's not being used and see if it works.