# XPiNC - Engine exception when running locally

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpinc

I have a relatively simple XPage, which is largely acting as a container for existing JavaScript/HTML.

This runs fine when accessed from a browser, however if I try to launch via the Notes client (which has identical launch properties), I get the following error message:

> **Engine Exception**
>
> **null**
>
> *IBM WebSphere Application Server*

And to be able to run from the Notes client is a requirement for the app :-(

However to further complicate matters, if I configure the app to 'Run server-based XPages apps directly on server', it renders fine on both the browser and Notes client.

The problem with this though is it requires authentication from the user before running, which wouldn't be acceptable for the app.

The app makes (minimal) use of the Extension Library and Domino API, which I've also installed on the Notes client, however disabling both in the application makes no difference to the symptoms.

Does anyone have any thoughts?  Sorry if I've posted in the wrong place...  wasn't sure if this was a StackOverflow or ServerFault problem (it kind of straddles the two).

Comment: Not sure if this is related to preview ports, seems you are getting further if you are getting Engine Exception, but have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413502/unable-to-start-the-process-of-nhttp-exe-on-my-local-machine-using-notes-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks pipalia, however this turned out to be a local issue with my install.

After creating a 'Hello World' XPage and finding it to exhibit the same issue, I gave my PC a health check (deleted cache.ndk in the data folder, and cleared out my c:\windows\temp and %temp% folders) which fixed the problem.